# Rails server - Is seeing a "query plan" in the logs related to server crash?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, crash, thinking-sphinx

I am running rails 3.2 in dev mode in a vagrant VM. I have a web interface that makes several queries with thinking sphinx (queries are sent via ajax). At times, the web interface may send a new query, and the front-end will ignore the response of any outstanding queries on which the server may be still be operating.

Occasionally, the rails serveK will die, the command line only says "Killed". Each time, it seems I see a "query plan" show up in the logs right before the server dies. I have an example from the logs below.

```
EXPLAIN for: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
                          QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..2.45 rows=1 width=2420)
   ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..2.45 rows=1 width=2420)
         Filter: (id = 1)
(3 rows)
```

Are these two things related? Could the database be the reason for the server crash? I can't find any other explanation or errors in the logs.

I've not seen this in production, perhaps my dev environment doesn't have enough resources?

Answer (score 0):

The "query plan" does not necessarily relates to the crash. These query plans are a verbose explanation of slow sql queries. So you will see this whenever there is a query slower than 5 seconds (the default is 5 seconds).
If your server is timing out, and these are showing, then it could be, slow queries that are slow enough to timeout the server. But if your server is erroring out, then it maybe something else.

Comment: Do you know where in the error logs I can check to see if the server crashed due to a timeout?

Comment: Hmm, you should see the error right when it crashes. You said you dont really see any errors, only 'server killed', that maybe sql query.